# How to trigger an OpenNMS event with thresholds

Tags: html, events, threshold, opennms, collectd

it seems that it is not possible for me to trigger an event in OpenNMS using a threshold...
first the fact (as much detail as i can)

1. i want to monitor a html file, better, the content.
2. if a value is not what i expected OpenNMS should call be.

my html file: 
Document Count: 5

in /var/lib/opennms/rrd/snmp/*NODE* are two files named: "documentCount" (.jbr & .meta)
--> because of the http-datacollection-config.xml

in my logfiles is written:

```
 INFO  [LegacyScheduler-Thread-2-of-50] RrdUtils: updateRRD: updating RRD file /var/lib/opennms/rrd/snmp/21/documentCount.jrb with values '1385031023:5'"
```

so the "5" is collected correctly.

now i created a threshold for this case:

```
<threshold type="high" ds-type="node"
    value="4.0" rearm="2.0" trigger="1" triggeredUEI="uei.opennms.org/threshold/highThresholdExceeded"
    filterOperator="or" ds-name="documentCount"
/>
```

in my collectd-configuration.xml is the threshold also enabled:

in my opinion the threshold of 4 is exceeded, because the value is 5. so the highTresholdEvent should be fired. BUT IT DOESNT.

so i'm here to ask if someone had an idea. 
regards dawn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check collectd.log with the following

```
tail -f collectd.log | grep -i thresholding
```

Threshold checking was moved to evaluate while the data is being retrieved a while back as opposed to a post process of rrd files.

Even with the log setting at info you should find some clues as to why the threshold rule is not matching any data.